# Stop printing the output of Counter() after a given number of lines

Tags: python

Trying to write a program that prints the *n* most common items in a list depending on how many the user wants to see, and prints more if the last items have the same frequency.

This is what i have written:

```
num = int(input("Enter Number"))
i = 0
wordsInList = [word1, word2, word2, word3, word1]
catagory = Counter(list)
catagory.keys()
for key, value in catagory.items(): #set the frequency to value and word to key
    if i <= num or lastValue == value: #(Issue with code)If the required number of values have been printed, stop printing
        print('{:<5d}{:<15s}'.format(value, key)) 
        lastValue = value
        i =+ 1
```

The problem with this is that as soon as that print statement is run, it prints all lines of the *count()*.

Comment: Where is `i` defined? Close your parens properly. This code won't run at all as posted.

Comment: Do not use `list` keyword as nabe of a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the built-in function `most_common` for the `Counter` class ([reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html)):

```
num = int(input("Enter Number"))
list = [word1, word2, word2, word3, word1]
counts = Counter(list)

most_common = counts.most_common(num)

# additional requirement by OP 
# of having more results if last items have same frequency

most_common_values = [elt[1] for elt in most_common]

ret = []
for k, v in most_common.items(): # python 3.5+
    if v in most_common_values:
        ret.append((k,v))

print(ret)
```